# How can I fetch Coverage Band Details from GeoServer in OpenLayers?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, web-mapping

[image]

I want to display the gray index value in the image above in GeoServer on my map when clicked
At the bottom of the example there is (layer preview-> openlayers) I want something like this

[image]

Comment: In what way is this question different then your previous one, except this time even relevant code is missing: [Get pixel value of ImageWMS that has geotiff format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388583/get-pixel-value-of-imagewms-that-has-geotiff-format)

Comment: I search in geoserver and find this section and I want fetch this information to my code and show gray_index of each point when clicked can you help me?

Comment: for the third time - you need to use a getfeatureinfo request like the preview page does

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Can you give me an example? and Does it work for the ImageWMS as well?